# How do I import a module while specifying an argument?

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have a main.py file, a mod.py module and a config.json configuration file.
When the program is run, the configuration file is passed as an argument. In main.py it is read to extract some information.

I want the module to get some parameters from the configuration file.

How can I do it ? Is it possible to specify some parameters when importing a module ? That would be perfect.

For now I have to send the whole config informations as a parameter each time I call a function from the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an initialisation method in the module (`mod.py`) like this:

```
_A = 0

def init(A):
    global _A
    _A = A

def func_a():
    print _A
```

And then use it like this in `main.py`:

```
import mod

mod.init(1)
mod.func_a()
```

You can also modify the modules variables like this:

```
mod._A = 2
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Definitely helping, thank you ! Although I didn't actually used a global variable.